# Is the following relation concerning $2D$ integrals true?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, multiple-integral

Fix $d,t>0$ and let $a \in L^2[-d,0]$ and $Y \in L^2[-d,t]$.

Is it true via some change of variable the following relation?

$$\int_{(-t) \vee (-d)}^0 \int_{-d}^s a(\xi)Y(\xi-s)d\xi d s+\int_0^t\int_{-d}^{0} I_{[-(t-s),0]}(\xi)a(\xi)Y(s) d \xi ds=\int_0^t\int_{-d}^{0} a(\xi)Y(s+\xi) d \xi ds$$

Comment: It's more complicated than that. Assuming the integral on the right is the correct result, I think the integral on the left correctly deals with positive values of $s$, but it is missing negative values of $s.$

Comment: You were right: there was a missing term, I added it. Like this seems correct? What do you suggest to do?